# set get position of an element

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, set

I want to solve the following problem: given a vector of n elements, find the number of swaps the insertion sort algorithm needs to sort.

Ex:
n = 5
2 1 3 1 2
Answer: 4

Explanation(step by step for insertion sort algorithm):
initialy: 2 1 3 1 2
1 2 3 1 2 ; **1** swap  1( 1 goes left)
1 2 3 1 2 ; **0** swaps
1 1 2 3 2 ; **2** swaps ( 1 goes 2 pos left )
1 1 2 2 3 ; **1** swap ( 2 goes 1 pos left)

### My solution

I keep the position of every item in the initial array so I can remove the from the set later based on value and position.(1st for loop)
Then I count the number of elements that are smaller than the current number add them to the counter and remove this element from the set. ( 2nd for loop )

As you can see, the problem is the std::distance which has [linear complexity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/) cause set has bidirectional iterators. How can I get O(1) complexity without having to implement my own tree?

```
int count_operations(vector<int> &v)
{
    set<pair<int, int>> s;
    // O(N * logN)
    for(int i = 0; i < (int) v.size(); ++i)
    {
        s.insert(make_pair(v[i], i));
    }
    int cnt = 0;
    // desired: O(N * log N) ; current O(N^2)
    for(int i = 0; i < (int) v.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto item = make_pair(v[i], i);
        auto it = s.find(item);
        int dist = distance(s.begin(), it);//O(N); I want O(1)
        s.erase(it);
        cnt += dist;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to modify the distance calculation without extending the tree structure to store additional data, but I can give you another solution to count number of swaps during insert sort, do you me to write it?

Comment: Why are you constructing the `set` to begin with?

Comment: Looks like you need a balanced tree where each node keeps track of the sizes of its subtrees. The tree structure used by `std::set` implementation does not. I'm afraid you would have to roll your own, after all.

Comment: @pkacprzak, sure, that's why I posted the problem too. I haven't found a better than O(NlogN) solution

Comment: @Igor. That's what I wanted to avoid. set was the closest with red-black tree implementation.

Comment: @DanLincan I can write an O(nlogn) solution based on the mergesort if you want?

Comment: @pkacprzak. I solved it with avl trees storing the number of left subnodes in each node, but still share your idea. Never bad to know more solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is getting the rank of each element in a set, which can be done with an order statistic tree (using the pbds library in gnu libc++) as follows.

```
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
using namespace __gnu_pbds;

typedef tree<
    pair<int, int>, /* key type */
    null_mapped_type, /* value type */
    less< pair<int, int> >, /* comparison */
    rb_tree_tag, /* for having an rb tree */
    tree_order_statistics_node_update> order_set;

int count_ops(std::vector<int> &v)
{
    order_set s;
    int cnt = 0;
    /* O(N*log(N)) */
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        s.insert(pair<int, int>(v[i], i));
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        /* finding rank is O(log(N)), so overall complexity is O(N*log(N)) */
        cnt += s.order_of_key(pair<int, int>(v[i], i));
        s.erase(pair<int, int>(v[i], i));
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: intersting, never knew about this library, however I don't have access to this library in the enviroment. I ended up implementing the tree myself and was wondering if there was a way to solve the problem using  only std algorithms and containers.

Comment: Well the PBDS library is really a template. So you can download all the relevant files and use them directly in your application, and no additional library should be required. The files will be a part of GNU libstdc++ release.

Comment: It works. It performs worse with no optimization flags compared to my custom implementation.However when -O2 is active, it get very close. How come there is so little knowledge about pb_ds? It is way more configurable than stl.